# How to run program in Cygwin using python (3.8) script from windows 10?

Tags: python, cygwin

I am trying to open the Cygwin terminal with the help of the python (3.8.3) script on my windows 10 laptop and execute two separate commands.

```py
        import subprocess
        from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
        import subprocess
        import os

        os.chdir(b"folder path")

        p = subprocess.Popen('C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -', 
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        p.stdin.write(b"cd newfolder")     #b in front to denote bytes object
        p.stdin.write(b"mysecondcommand")     #stdin doesn't take strings
        p.stdin.close()
```

I can open the Cygwin terminal with python script but my commands are not executed, can anyone help with this?

Comment: maybe add`p.stdin.write(b"\n") `  after your inputs? because I think you forgot to press enter.

Comment: Why not just use built-in functionality to change the current working directory, and then run `mysecondcommand` normally?

Comment: @TijmenMeijer   Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried it, but it didn’t work.